# How to show query to database in ListView in kotlin with android studio?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-room

I am learning to develop in kotlin with android studio, so I don't have any experience.

I am wanting to insert data into a local database using room database, so far I think I'm doing fine. Now I need to be able to consult those data but I cannot do it, I have searched the internet but I have not been able to solve my problem.
I attach the code.

Class @Entity

```
class TablasBdApp {
@Entity(tableName = TblConteo.TABLE_NAME)
data class TblConteo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "linea_id") val Linea_Id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo (name = "articulo") val Articulo : String?
)
{
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "TablaConteo"
    }
}
}
```

Class @Dao

```
@Dao
public interface ItblConteoDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertArticulo(taskTblConteo: TablasBdApp.TblConteo);

@Query("SELECT * FROM " + TablasBdApp.TblConteo.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY Linea_Id desc")
fun getConteoArticulos(): LiveData<List<TablasBdApp.TblConteo>>
}
```

Class @DataBase

```
class BaseDeDatos {
@Database(entities = [TablasBdApp.TblConteo::class], version = 1)
abstract class PortatilDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun itblconteoDao () : ItblConteoDao
    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "portatildb"
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: PortatilDataBase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): PortatilDataBase? {
                INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        PortatilDataBase::class.java,
                        DATABASE_NAME
                    ).build()
                }
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
}
```

Class @Repository

```
class ConteoRepository(application: Application) {
private val itblConteoDao: ItblConteoDao? = BaseDeDatos.PortatilDataBase.getInstance(application)?.itblconteoDao()

fun insert (tblconteo: TablasBdApp.TblConteo){
    if(itblConteoDao != null) InsertAsyncTask(itblConteoDao).execute(tblconteo)
}

fun getConteo(): LiveData<List<TablasBdApp.TblConteo>> {
    return itblConteoDao?.getConteoArticulos() ?: MutableLiveData<List<TablasBdApp.TblConteo>>()
}

private class InsertAsyncTask(private val itblConteoDao: ItblConteoDao) :
    AsyncTask<TablasBdApp.TblConteo, Void, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg tblconteos: TablasBdApp.TblConteo?): Void? {
        for (tblconteo in tblconteos) {
            if (tblconteo != null) itblConteoDao.insertArticulo(tblconteo)
        }
        return null
    }
}
}
```

Class @CustomAdapter

```
class CustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {
private val mContext: Context
init{
    mContext = context
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    //val repository = ConteoRepository(application = Application())
    var textView = TextView(mContext)
    val observer = Observer<List<TablasBdApp.TblConteo>> { conteos ->
        if (conteos != null) {
            var text = ""

            for (conteo in conteos) {
                text += conteo.Linea_Id.toString() + " " + conteo.Articulo
            }
            textView.text = text
        }
    }
    //repository.getConteo().observe(this, observer)
    return textView
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return "Test Articulo"
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

}
```

Class @Fragment

```
class CapturaConteoFragment() : Fragment() {

private lateinit var capturaConteoViewModel: CapturaConteoViewModel

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    capturaConteoViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CapturaConteoViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_capturaconteo, container, false)
    //val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_capturaconteo)
    capturaConteoViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        //textView.text = it

        val botonGuardar: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_guardar)
        val textoArticulo : EditText = root.findViewById(R.id.edit_art_upc)
        var listview: ListView = root.findViewById(R.id.list_conteo)

        botonGuardar.setOnClickListener {
           if(textoArticulo.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
               Toast.makeText(activity, "Captura un articulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               textoArticulo.requestFocus()
           }
            else{
               saveConteo(TablasBdApp.TblConteo(Articulo = textoArticulo.text.trim().toString()))
               Toast.makeText(activity, "Articulo guardado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

               //var listaconteo = arrayOf(muestraConteo())
               var prodAdapter = CustomAdapter(**this**) **<- This is where it marks error.** 
               listview?.adapter = prodAdapter
           }
        }
    })
    return root
}

private fun saveConteo(tblConteo: TablasBdApp.TblConteo) {
    val repository = ConteoRepository(application = Application())

    repository.insert(tblConteo)

    val conteo = repository.getConteo()
}

private fun showConteo (){
    val repository = ConteoRepository(application = Application())
    repository.getConteo()
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your **DAO** you are returning **LiveData** that means you need to **observe** it and best practice would be through **ViewModel** which implies you should MVVM architecture, there are plenty of tutorials and courses on it.
[Here is something from google Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0)

Other way would would be to return just list rather than live data of a list. This is bad practice because you will have to refresh it all the time and do a lot of extra work.

PS your adapter needs fixing too my suggestion is follow codelabs or watch complete tutorial on **Room + MVVM**.

Hope this helps